# Installing new version of linux on vary old

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a compact version of linux, build from ubuntu V10 and kernel v3.13. Now because of hardware changes, i need to replace it by newest kernel. When I try to update in directly, after downloading latest *deb files from kernel.ubuntu.com when i try to install them  via dpkg command, i receive error "archive *** contains not understood data member control.tar.xz" ...

Can somebody help me with solution?

Comment: Does "ubuntu V10" mean you're using Ubuntu 10.04? From 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not just upgrading Ubuntu? It has a built-in upgrade mechanism, that will give you newer kernels. Manually upgrading just the kernel witch such large version differences will probably cause problems.

Comment: It sounds like the OP may be using some customized spin (not a standard release), of a very old version.  The built-in upgrade typically works from one major release to the next, but not many generations, and may not handle a customized spin (it doesn't have the meta files to know what is supposed to be in it).  It also probably can't be upgraded by just looking at the packages, because a much different set of packages may compose the current version.  These kinds of upgrades tend to be a lot more hands-on.  But you're also probably right that just a kernel upgrade may not do it.